# Identifying one field from three fields where the value of field is equal to specific number in `MySQL`

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three fields (a,b,c) in one table: `sample_table`.
One of the value in these three fields is 999.

I want to select only that column whose value is 999.
Let's assume `b = 999`.

I want to select these three with b value as 1 and other two values as 0.

Note that there are many rows with one of the values as 999.

Comment: Please add sample input and output data.

Comment: Your table has _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, a simple case when will work:

```
select 
case when b = 999 then 1
when a = 999 then 0
when c = 999 then 0
end
from sample_table
```